# Null Hypothesis with a Strict Inequality

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

On page 300 in Roussas' textbook "An Introduction to Probability and Statistical Inference" he states the null hypothesis for a test as $H_0: \theta>0.0625$ and the alternate hypothesis as $H_A: \theta \leq 0.0625$. What value of $\theta$ does one use to calculate the distribution of the test statistic under the null hypothesis in this test?

Comment: The issue here is not that there is a "strict inequality", but that the null hypothesis is *composite* in the sense that it comprises more than one possible distribution of a minimal sufficient statistic. The standard theory of this situation is that of [uniformly most powerful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_most_powerful_test) (UMP) tests.

Comment: If H0 had been expressed as theta > or = to 0.0625 I would use theta = 0.0625 to calculate the power function. Since there is no equality, I can't do that. The question is what value of theta do I use to calculate the power function for this null hypothesis?

Comment: The distinction is of no consequence. When the space of possible distributions is partitioned into two sets $\Theta_0$ and $\Theta_1$ corresponding to the null and alternative hypotheses, respectively, the principle you are following is to use the worst value of $\theta$ in $\Theta_0$. This worst value--which is a *supremum* rather than a maximum--might not be attained by any particular element of $\Theta_0$. Under normal regularity assumptions, it *will* be attained within the closure of $\Theta_0$. The closure of $\{\theta\,|\,\theta\gt 1/16\}$ is the set $\{\theta\,|\,\theta\ge 1/16\}$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I asked this question because I have been taught to always put the equality in the null hypothesis and this is the first time I have seen things done otherwise. You seem to be telling me that it is technically OK to use theta = 0.0625 in the calculation anyway even though the hypotheses are not stated that way. I will take that to be the short answer to my question.

Comment: I think your interpretation is good. The answer posted by @behzad.nouri is more accurate, though: the endpoint $\theta=1/16$ is the one to use only when the null hypothesis has a particular form. (This motivates the interest in monotone likelihood ratio families mentioned in [the Wikipedia article on UMP tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_most_powerful_test#Important_case:_The_exponential_family).) In more general situations it is not always the case that the endpoint is the one to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Value of $\theta$ which makes it *least* likely for the null-hypothesis to be rejected; i.e.

$$ \underset{.0625\,<\,\theta } {\mathrm{argmax}} \,\, L(X; \theta)$$

where $L(X; \theta)$ is the likelihood of observation $X$ with parameter $\theta$. Note that for the purposes of hypothesis test, in fact you do not need to solve above for $\theta$ but all you need is

$$ \underset{.0625\,<\,\theta} {\mathrm{max}} \,\, \mathrm{P}(X;\theta) $$

which may exists in terms of *limit* even though $.0625\,<\,\theta$ is not a *closed* set.

By doing so, you can guarantee that if you manage to reject the null-hypothesis with $1 - \alpha$ significance, then you have *at least* $1 - \alpha$ confidence that the null hypothesis is not *true*, because any other value of $\theta$ under the null will give even more confidence in rejecting the null hypothesis.

Comment: can you suggest a specific statistics textbook that discusses what you have presented here? Thanks.